# CreateToolHelp32Snapshot for 64bit to 32bit (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net

Well this works perfect to grab modules from 32bit process to other 32bit process when using dwFlags 8
But with 64bit to 32bit it fails with dwFlags set to 10 as MSDN says
I can't seem to see what I have to change more when using it in a 64bit compile.

```
Structure MODULEENTRY32
  Dim U32Size As UInteger
  Dim Th32ModuleId As UInteger
  Dim Th32ProcessId As UInteger
  Dim GlblcntUsage As UInteger
  Dim ProccntUsage As UInteger
  Dim ModBaseAddr As Byte
  Dim ModBaseSize As UInteger
  Dim HModule As Integer
  <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=256)> Dim SzModule As String
  <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=260)> Dim SzeExePath As String
End Structure

Private Function ModuleBase(ByVal strModule As String) As Integer
  Dim p() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(Gname)
  Dim hSnapshot As IntPtr = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(&H10, CUInt(p(0).Id))
  If hSnapshot = IntPtr.Zero Then Return Nothing
  Dim me32Modules As New MODULEENTRY32
  me32Modules.U32Size = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(me32Modules))
  If Module32First(hSnapshot, me32Modules) Then
  Do
        If strModule = (me32Modules.SzModule) Then Return me32Modules.HModule
  Loop While (Module32Next(hSnapshot, me32Modules))
  End If
  Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: What does it do? Does the call fail? If so, what does `GetLastError` say?

Comment: You MODULEENTRY32 declaration is wrong.  You got away with it in 32-bit mode (barely), not in 64-bit mode.  ModBaseAddr and HModule are IntPtr.